# Istanbul check-coverage always return true

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, code-coverage, istanbul

I'm trying to setup `npm` to check coverage using `istanbul`. Here are my scripts from `package.json` :

```
"scripts": {
    "coverage:report": "istanbul cover _mocha --",
    "coverage:check": "istanbul check-coverage",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha test/hooks.js test/**/*.spec.js",
}
```

I also this two configuration files :

**.istanbul.yml**

```
instrumentation:
    root: app
check:
    global:
        statements: 100
        lines: 100
        branches: 100
        functions: 100
```

**mocha.opts**

```
--reporter spec
--ui bdd
--recursive
--colors
```

When I run `npm run coverage:report` I get the following output :

```
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 98.69% ( 301/305 )
Branches     : 95.08% ( 58/61 )
Functions    : 100% ( 22/22 )
Lines        : 98.65% ( 293/297 )
================================================================================
```

So `npm run coverage:check` is supposed to fail, but it is not. Here is the output I get

```
npm run coverage:check

> ...@2.0.0 coverage:check /home/.../.../...-v2-server
> istanbul check-coverage
```

What did I miss ?

Comment: Can you try replacing the node `check - global` in your `yml` file with `thresholds`?

Comment: The problem remains the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still don't why it is not working, but I switch to `nyc` and it is working with the following config

**.nycrc**

```
{
    "reporter": [
        "lcov",
        "text-summary"
    ],
    "include": [
        "app/**/*.js",
        "test/utils/**/*.js",
        "test/fixtures/**/*.js"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "test/**/*.spec.js"
    ],
    "lines": 100,
    "statements": 100,
    "functions": 100,
    "branches": 100,
    "check-coverage": true
}
```

**test/mocha.opts**

```
--reporter spec
--ui bdd
--recursive
--colors
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint *.js --cache",
  "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix"
  "start": "node -e 'require(\"./app\").start()' | bunyan",
  "test": "nyc ./node_modules/.bin/mocha test/hooks.js test/**/*.spec.js"
},
```

Comment: how can i set each file coverage limit i.e, default the coverage check is taking for the global coverage , how can i set for each file similar to Istanbul.ymls each